# Get the dataframe based on top two values of a group in grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

My dataframe `df` is:

```
data = {'Election Year':['2000', '2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2000','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005','2005', '2010', '2010','2010','2010','2010','2010','2010','2010', '2010'],
    'Votes':[30, 50, 20, 26, 30, 45, 20, 46, 80, 60, 46, 95, 60, 10, 95, 16, 65, 35, 50, 100, 70, 26, 180, 100, 120, 46, 80], 
    'Party': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Region': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','c', 'c', 'c','a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','c', 'c', 'c','a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b','c', 'c', 'c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    
    Election Year   Votes   Party   Region
  0   2000           30      A       a
  1   2000           50      B       a
  2   2000           20      C       a
  3   2000           26      A       b
  4   2000           30      B       b
  5   2000           45      C       b 
  6   2000           20      A       c
  7   2000           46      B       c
  8   2000           80      C       c
  9   2005           60      A       a
  10  2005           46      B       a
  11  2005           95      C       a
  12  2005           60      A       b
  13  2005           10      B       b
  14  2005           95      C       b
  15  2005           16      A       c
  16  2005           65      B       c
  17  2005           35      C       c
  18  2010           50      A       a
  19  2010           100     B       a
  20  2010           70      C       a
  21  2010           26      A       b
  22  2010           180     B       b
  23  2010           100     C       b 
  24  2010           120     A       c
  25  2010           46      B       c
  26  2010           80      C       c
```

I want to get the sub-datframe showing minimum votes that each party in the top 2 of the 2010 election secured among all the past elections considering every region.
So the desired output is:

```
 Election Year   Party   Votes   Region
     2005         B       10        b
     2000         C       20        a
```

First I tried to get the top two parties based on aggregate total votes of year 2010. But it is giving top 2 parties of each year.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Election Year','Party'])['Votes'].sum().reset_index()
df1 = df1.sort_values(['Election Year','Votes'], ascending=False)
top_2 = df1.groupby('Election Year').head(8).reset_index()
top_2 = top_2[['Election Year', 'Party']].to_string(index=False)
top_2
```

How to fix this to get top 2 parties of 2010 and then check for the minimum votes among all years.

Comment: In your attempt you never select data only from 2010. Did you try doing that? That would be the first thing I did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the party who is top 2 in 2010 elections:

```
m=df['Election Year'].eq('2010')
#create a msk to check condition
party=df[m].groupby(['Election Year','Party'],as_index=False)['Votes'].sum().sort_values('Votes',ascending=False).head(2)['Party'].values
#passed that mask and then grouping and sort values in descending order and get top 2 parties name
```

Finally get the minimum votes of those 2 parties:

```
out=df[df['Party'].isin(party)].sort_values('Votes').drop_duplicates(subset=['Party'])
#checking minimum votes only for those parties
```

Now if you print `out` you will get your expected output

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. First part is giving only top two parties but not based on total maximum votes in 2010. Do I need to sort in descending order of Votes to get the two largest parties in 2010? Top two parties in 2010 is B and C.

Comment: @Dpk ohh you are right...Updated answer....kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 0):

First we try to extract the top-2 performing parties for the year 2010.

```
top_2_in_2010 = df[df['Election Year'] == 2010].groupby(['Election Year', 'Party'], \
       as_index = False).sum().sort_values('Votes', ascending = False)['Party'][:2].values
```

Create dataframe for previous years:

```
df_2 = df[df['Election Year'] < 2010][df['Party'].isin(top_2_in_2010)]
```

Finally,

```
result = df_2.sort_values('Votes', ascending = True).head(2)
```

Printing out **result** will give you the desired output.